# Change "," on "." in android

Tags: android

I have a string where I have a value: 2,6. How can I change "," on "." I use `x.replace(",", ".");` but doesn't work. This is any other method to do that?

Comment: - Declare a new string
- Iterate over all characters in your input string
- If currentChar == ',', add '.' to the new string, else, add currentChar.
- Return new string.

Comment: x = x.replaceAll(",","."); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949988/string-replace-in-java

Comment: Yup, that would be way better. (I was just giving a last resort ;D)

Comment: You already have 3 correct answers, but let me ask you where does this string come from? I'm just asking because I have seen people output numbers in whatever locale is defined in the system and afterwards replace dots with commas and vice versa instead of using the correct locale right away...

Comment: define doesn't work, post your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
x = x.replace(",",".");
```

In Java, Strings are immutable, so you will always get a new String from the operations. You have to store this new String, or your changes are lost. `replace()` returns a new String object, so you need to keep a reference to this new object. Your older String is not modified.

Answer (score 2):

String is immutable it create the new object again after modifying in string. So You need to assign the result.

Do like this.

```
x= x.replace(",", ".");
```

Comment: I was wondering the same thing about this and the other -1 answer.

Answer (score 2):

Correct way is:

```
x = x.replace(",", ".");
```

String is immutable, it can't be changed. `x.replace` creates a new string

Comment: Wondering who is downvoting all these _correct_ answers. Care to explain?