# How to modify string value in Insert statement using java

Tags: java, string, postgresql, jdbc

I have insert query like below

```
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.STAFF(NAME, PICTURE,EMAIL) VALUES
('samplePic', X'89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4', 'some@domain.com');
```

How to modify above Picture attribute string value (`X'89504e47` to `\x89504e47`) and final Query is will be like.

```
 INSERT INTO PUBLIC.STAFF(NAME, PICTURE,EMAIL) VALUES
    ('samplePic', '\x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4', 'some@domain.com');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String replace in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949988/string-replace-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `replace` method like this:

```
 String query = "INSERT INTO PUBLIC.STAFF(NAME, PICTURE,EMAIL) VALUES('samplePic', X'89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4', 'some@domain.com')";
 query = query.replace("X'89504e47", "'\\x89504e47");
```

Output:

```
 INSERT INTO PUBLIC.STAFF(NAME, PICTURE,EMAIL) VALUES('samplePic', '\x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4', 'some@domain.com')
```

Comment: But we have to use regular expression for getting exact binary string match

Answer (score -4):

you should write as below.

UPDATE PUBLIC.STAFF SET PICTURE ='x89504e47' where NAME ='samplePic';